# Data in AJAX callback function is undefined in IE8 only

Tags: jquery

I wrote a page called `test.jsp` to learn how to get data from a server. The JS code for test.jsp:

I didn't add `{async: false}` option at first, but it didn't work as well.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $.get(
            "./tabServlet?t=" + new Date(),
            { async: false },
            function(data) {
                alert(data);
            }
        );
    });
</script>
```

Critical code for a simple servlet:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException, IOException 
{
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    out.print("12345");
    out.close();
}
```

The problem is that in IE8, `alert(data)` shows `undefined`. The same code works fine with Chrome. Can anyone tell me why this is?

Comment: You may want to use `new Date()`.valueOf(), because that produces a query parameter without spaces. IE8 may not like having spaces in the URL.

Comment: i tried, not work as well. i think the callback function runs,so there is nothing wrong with the URL,right?

Comment: The URL is probably fine. You should also try specifying the datatype that you are expecting in $.get. Also, the "async" parameter that you are sending is being sent as a GET parameter to the server, which has nothing to with whether or not you are making an async request. Checkout the JQuery documentation for [$.get()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried this in IE8 and it worked fine. 
You can debug the code and see what's wrong with your code, first make sure the response "12345" is returned.